# How to install Big Blue Button 2.7.0 on Ubuntu Server 20.04.6 LTS as such to not use a SSL certificate

Tags: server, 20.04, webserver, installed-programs, moodle

**Context:**

1. I'm trying to install Big Blue Button 2.7.0 on Ubuntu Server 20.04.6 LTS without the automatic Let's Encrypt Certbot thing because "[CAA record for <supradomain> prevents issuance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/760957/big-blue-button-installation-error-challenge-failed-for-domain-thereafter-5)" anyways;
2. I have the certificate as ".key" and ".pem" files and would like to configure this certificate manually after installing, so no Let's Encrypt should be employed at any point of the installation process;
3. But I expected BigBlueButton to be accessible through HTTP between installation and SSL configuration, in order to test if my setup is correct upt to that point.

**What have I tried:**

1. I have followed [the official "Install BigBlueButton" guide](https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/administration/install/) and the server meets all [the minimum requirements](https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/administration/install/#minimum-server-requirements) ([I checked](https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/administration/install/#pre-installation-checks));
2. I have used the command `wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bigbluebutton/bbb-install/v2.7.x-release/bbb-install.sh | bash -s -- -v focal-270 -d -s bbb27.<supradomain>.edu.br` to install BigBlueButton.
3. The server gives me "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" when I try to access it through HTTP, which seems to be automatically redirecting me to HTTPS, which is not desired.
4. I have previously tried not using the arguments `-s bbb27.<supradomain>.edu.br` and also `-d`, but, as I got other type of errors, I have reached the conclusion that using both `-s bbb27.<supradomain>.edu.br` and `-d` should be tried. Maybe I'm wrong?

**Arguments detailing:**

Source: [Command options @ GitHub](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bbb-install#command-options).

> -v            Install given version of BigBlueButton (e.g. 'focal-270') (required)
>
> -d                     Skip SSL certificates request (use provided certificates from mounted volume) in /local/certs/
>
> -s           Configure server with <hostname>

**Questions:**

1. Why am I getting the "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"?
2. How to set up the server to allow HTTP accesses?

Comment: [Asked also on BigBlueButton Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/bigbluebutton-setup/c/u3yareS8MkI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to set up the server to allow HTTP accesses?

You don't.

The premise of first installing and only later configuring the certificate is flawed.

What you do: you install AND configure the server.

How?

Use `-d`, like you did, but pay attention to how it is described:

> Skip SSL certificates request (use provided certificates from mounted volume) in /local/certs/

This means you should put the certificates on /local/certs with these exact names:

- /local/certs/privkey.pem
- /local/certs/fullchain.pem

BigBlueButton will do everything else that is needed and your server will be up and running.

**Source:** [sdame@distancelearning.cloud on BigBlueButton's official Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/bigbluebutton-setup/c/u3yareS8MkI/m/fEbmggLuAAAJ).